# prevent direct access to php page , but allow from javascript src

Tags: javascript, php, url

is there any way I prevent direct access to my php gage but allow from javascript?

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mypage.php?p=a"></script>
```

on mypage.php I have this code

```
<?php   
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
    exit;
}
else
{

$mycode="something here";

echo "document.write(\" $mycode \")";

}
?>
```

it is work fine if some one type url in browser, but if some one open mypage.php as a link

```
<a href=http://mywebsite.com/mypage.php>link</a>
```

, I want to prevent opening the page, is there any way to do that using php or javascript?

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` should contain your domains name if requested from inside your HTML (<script>)

Comment: Think of JavaScript as simply automating user actions. Anything your JS can do, a user can do. It might take a bit of work on the user's part, but they can do it if they really want. They can fake their referrers and extract anything you send to the browser.

Comment: Not to mention that people can look at the script source code right in their browser's dev tools. This is an XY problem, please tell us what your *actual* problem is, instead of asking about what you think is a solution for it.